# Is is safe to make assumptions about class layout after multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, memory, casting, multiple-inheritance

As far as I know, order in case of multiple inheritance is the same of the oder of called constructors. This questions is about the memory layout?

Considering the following snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
    void seta() {a = 1;}
    int a;
};

class B {
    public:
    void setb() {b = 2;}
    int b;
};

class C : public A, public B {
};

class D : public B, public A {
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.a = 1;
    c.b = 2;
    void * p1 = (void *)(&c);
    //if layout is as inheritance order, always displays C.a: 1 C.b: 1?
    std::cout << "C.a: " << ((A*)(p1))->a << " C.b: " << ((B*)(p1))->b << "\n";
    D d;
    d.a = 1;
    d.b = 2;
    void * p2 = (void *)(&d);
    //if layout is as inheritance order, always displays D.a: 2 D.b: 2?
    std::cout << "D.a: " << ((A*)(p2))->a << " D.b: " << ((B*)(p2))->b << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Is it safe to rely on the two hypothese in comments?
In terms of memory layout, and because of inheritance order, are C and D object equivalent to:

```
class C {
    public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

class D {
    public:
    int b;
    int a;
};
```

? Or is it depending on the implementation and then it is unsafe to rely on that?

Comment: not an answer, but if you use `dynamic_cast` and get rid of the `void*` then you do not need to make such assumption

Comment: @idclev463035818 I agree, this sample is more like an example to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 3):

In n4659 draft, [class.derived] says explicitely in §5:

> The order in which the base class subobjects are allocated in the most derived object (4.5) is unspecified.

It is enough to say that *unless a specific implementation specifies it* you should not rely on the order of the base classes subobjects.

Comment: what does allocation means exactly here? Does it really refer to the layout?

Comment: @FlashMcQueen: No. But my C-ish code uses `strdup` which internally allocates a dynamic character array with `alloc`. So it must be freed when it is no longer used.